# iOS: editing MKPolygon's alpha

Tags: ios, polygon, alpha

I'm using many MKPolygon objects in my app to display various elements in its mapview. I'm looking to be a bit more flexible with the controlling of these objects and wish to be able to edit the alpha of them for particular methods. As far as I can tell the class does not have an alpha property. The closest I can get to is to use the MKPolygonView but I can't seem to get this to work on an adhoc basis (the method in question is called when a particular button is pressed), and I'm not sure how multiple MKPolygonviews would work in one map.

So what could I do to easily adjust the alpha value of an MKPolygon instance?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The alpha value is a property of the `UIColor` class. So you have to create a color with alpha component and assign it to the `MKPolygonView`.

use this to create the color

```
(UIColor *)colorWithRed:(CGFloat)red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue alpha:(CGFloat)alpha;
```

A alpha value of 0.5 is 50% transparent.

Use the properties

`fillColor` or `strokeColor` from `MKPolygonView` to assign the color.

Comment: If you finally get transparent polygons, please do not forget to accept the answer (check box)

Comment: Unfortunately I could not get this to show any difference in the alpha of the polygon after it has already been created.

Comment: This is correct, after creation you cannot change it anymore. You have to remove the MkPolygon from view and add again, which may cause flickering.